# Can not cast tabBarController.viewController to UINavigationController

Tags: swift, core-data, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I added an UITabBarController to my storyboard, as I load managedContext in my Appdelegate I want to pass it to my initial ViewController. But I can not cast viewControllers to UINavigationControllers and therefor managedContext does not load.

This is my code:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarVC")
        self.window?.rootViewController = controller



        guard let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else {
            print("1")
            return true
        }
        guard let navController = tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as? UINavigationController else {
            print("2")
            return true
        }
        guard let viewController = navController.topViewController as? ViewController else {

               print("3")

                return true

        }

//  Version that works for UINavigationController
//        guard let navController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController,
//            let viewController = navController.topViewController as? ViewController else {
//                return true
//        }


        viewController.managedContext = coreDataStack.managedContext
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

The code was working when I was simple using an UINavigationController. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I bypassed the navigation controller and put the seque directly to the ViewController. It works now!

Comment: I tried to reproduce but couldn't. Are you certain that you embedded the `UITabBarController`'s first view controller in a `UINavigationController` in your storyboard?

Comment: Thanks, I bypassed the navigation controller and put the seque directly to the ViewController.

Comment: Right, so `ViewController` wasn't embedded in a `UINavigationController`. If you actually want to use `UINavigationController` you can just embed `ViewController` in a `UINavigationController` and your original code will work.

Answer (score 1):

good, work

```
if let tabbarcontroller = segue.destination as? UITabBarController
{
    let navigationController = tabbarcontroller.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
    let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! HomeController
    controller.account = sender as? Account
}
```